# This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct). when Sign out from flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies, google-signin

I'm using Firebase with Flutter to create a login method. However, when I log out of my account in the Flutter app, I get the following error:

```
This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
```

Then when I log in after this error, I get this error:

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

Here is my logout code:

```
Future<void> signOut() async {
    if (googleSignIn.currentUser != null){
      await googleSignIn.disconnect();
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();}
    else{
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
  
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => const AuthPage(),
        ),
            (route) => false,
      );
    });

  }
```

And here is the sign in code:

```
Future googleLogin() async{
     timer1 = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 1500), (){
       Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
     });
     showDialog(context: context,
       barrierDismissible: false,
       builder: (context) =>   Center(
         child: SizedBox(
           width: 150, height: 150,
           child: LiquidCircularProgressIndicator(


             backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF5B84B1),
             valueColor: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.white),



           ),
         ),
       ),
     ).then((value) {
       timer1!.cancel();
     });
     try {
       final googleUser =
       await GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['profile', 'email']).signIn();
       if (googleUser == null) return;
       _user = googleUser;

       final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

       final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
         accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
         idToken: googleAuth.idToken,

       );

       UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(
           credential);

       if (userCredential.additionalUserInfo!.isNewUser == true) {
         if (!mounted) return;

         Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
           context,
           MaterialPageRoute(
             builder: (BuildContext context) => const ProfilePage(),
           ),
               (route) => false,
         );
       }
       else {
         if (!mounted) return;

         Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
           context,
           MaterialPageRoute(
             builder: (BuildContext context) => const HomeScreen(),
           ),
               (route) => false,
         );
       }
     } on PlatformException catch (e) {
       Utils.showSnackBar(e.toString());
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if it is mounted or not, then proceed:

```dart
if (mounted) {
  // All the action is here
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but it didnt work for me. I am still getting the same error

Comment: What do you get after removing `addPostFrameCallback`

Comment: The same error. Actually i have added this part recently trying to solve the error

Comment: I am not sure if the signout is the actual problem and causing it cause I am getting many errors in different senarieos and I am trying to get to the root cause to solve it

Comment: for example the error I mentioned in the question that when I sign in I get:  setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
I tried to wrap all the setstate functions in the app with if mounted but it doesnt seem to be solved

Comment: and once the state error is thrown then the app crashes and I get : Failed assertion: line 2845 pos 18: '!navigator._debugLocked': is not true.
E/flutter (29465): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patc

Comment: About current error, it is getting because widget is nt mounted, It would be easy if you create two small widgets that will reproduce the same error

Comment: alright, thanks for your help and I will keep trying on solving this matter

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you are changing state inside a page lower in tree and then trying to access it from higher level of page in case of provider package same goes for firebase you're probably signing in and status is not transferred to the parent page.

Comment: How can I make sure that the status is transferred to the parent page?

Comment: So far I haven't faced this issue so maybe someone else knows it in detail. This just is a mere possibility that I think you're facing.